# About the definition of axiomatizable theory and consistency

Tags: logic

> Definition: If $A$ is a theory and $B \subseteq A$ then $B$ is a set
>   of axioms for $A$ iff 1) B is recursive and 2) $B \models C$ for all
>   $C \in A$. We say $A$ is axiomatizable iff $A$ has a set of axioms.

How can any theory be axiomatizable with this definition? If both theories prove the same set of sentences then wouldn't those sentences belong in both theories and $B = A$?

> Definition: A theory $A$ is consistent iff it's not equal to the set
>   of sentences in the Language of Arithmetic (with no free variables).

I thought that a consistent set is just one that doesn't have any contradictions. Does this definition relate to that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Note that a set of sentences is not the same as the set of sentences that can be derived from the given set oif sentences.

2) Once your theory contains *any* contradiction, you can prove *anything* (*ex falso quodlibet* - with mild assumptions about the allowed rules of inference)

Comment: Oh ok. I understand the first part, but I still don't understand why we can conclude a theory is consistent as long as it's not equal to the sentences in language of arithmetic?

Comment: @user5306 - clearly, your def is "extrapolated" form some parte regarding first-order theories of arithmetic. As per Hagen's answer, if a theory is *incons*, then it proves anything. Thus, if there is at least one sentence which is **not** provable, then the theory is *cons*. The above def boils down to this fact : a theory (in the language of arithmetic) is *cons* iff cannot prove all sentences expressible in the language (of arithmetic).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks I understand now